# parsing border styles in xslt

Tags: xslt

```
border: 3pt solid rgb(95, 73, 122); or border: solid  3pt rgb(95, 73, 122);
```

This is my input style. I want to take 3(before pt), solid and rgb(95,73,122). it may be in any order.how to do it using xslt 1.0. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the meaning of *"I want to take"*?

Comment: @Alex Nikoleankov: Tokenization in XSLT 1.0 without extensions is an answered FAQ. But I don't need nor want to guess what is being asked here...

Comment: Here i want to store the width(3), style(solid) and color(rgb(95,73,122)) in three variables..In some cases, my input may be border: solid 3pt rgb(95, 73, 122);..It has to work for this case too..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substring-before](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-before.html) and [substring-after](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-after.html) function and concat the results :

```
substring-before($input, 'pt'); => "border: 3"


substring-after($input, 'border:') =>  "solid  3pt rgb(95, 73, 122);"
```

Comment: This is fine, but it will not work for border: 3pt solid rgb(95, 73, 122); to fetch the width(3).